# Image pixel coordinates

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm using PHP and ImageMagick to read colors from an image's edge.

```
$x = 1;
$y = 1;
$pixel = $image->getImagePixelColor($x, $y);
$colors = $pixel->getColor(); // rgba
```

But I don't quite get how the coordinates work. So I created this 4px png.

[image]

`1,1` gives `rgba(0,30,255,0)` instead of the transparent pixel. Also, what if I select a large range of pixels?

Comment: According to the RGBA value that you are getting back, you are indeed selecting the transparent pixel. The 'a' stands for the Alpha Channel, normally used for Opacity. A value of 0 for 'a' means that it is fully transparent.

Comment: @User5842 Right, but why the rgb of blue `0,30,255` ?

Comment: What happens if you try to set that pixel with the RGBA value? The RGB value can still be `0,30,255`, it just means _blue with opacity_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to understand this is to remember that when a pixel is transparent, its colour becomes irrelevant, *yet it **is** retained*.

So, if we make an opaque 512x512 image of random noise, like this:

```
convert -size 512x512 xc:gray +noise random a.png
```

[image]

and check its size, you can see it is 1.5MB:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff   1.5M 26 Oct 09:14 a.png
```

If I now make an otherwise identical, transparent version:

```
convert -size 512x512 xc:gray +noise random -alpha transparent b.png
```

You can see the file has got bigger (at 1.7MB), because it is now storing transparency AND the original random data. I won't show the image because there is nothing to see:

```
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff   1.7M 26 Oct 09:16 b.png
```

I can now make the transparency layer fully opaque and the random pixels become visible again - so they were still there all along - even when the image was transparent:

```
convert b.png -alpha opaque c.png
```

[image]

If, however, I make the pixels transparent again, AND also set them all to the colour of the image background (since their colour is irrelevant), like this:

```
 convert -size 512x512 xc:gray +noise random -alpha transparent -alpha background d.png 

-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff   1.8K 26 Oct 09:22 d.png
```

And now suddenly the 1.5MB file is nearly 1,000 times smaller at 1.8K because it compresses much better as all the (invisible/transparent) colours are one single, solid background colour.

In answer to your question about coordinates. We can make a little image like this:

```
convert -size 1x1             \
       xc:red xc:cyan +append \
    \( xc:yellow xc:magenta +append \) -append a.png
```

[image]

And dump it like this:

```
convert a.png txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 2,2,65535,srgb
0,0: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
1,0: (0,65535,65535)  #00FFFF  cyan
0,1: (65535,65535,0)  #FFFF00  yellow
1,1: (65535,0,65535)  #FF00FF  magenta
```

And see that pixel coordinates in ImageMagick start at top-left corner.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed explanation! Got it now.

Answer (score 1):

**Coordinate system for pixels on screen/image :**

Any pixel system starts from bottom leftmost point of the screen/image called **origin**. Mapping of pixel starts from 0th index. (i.e. Green point in picture will be having (0,0) coordinates). [image]

---

Example :

```
Green pixel => (0,0)
Transparent => (1,0)
Blue => (1,1)
Red => (0,1)
```

---

> You do not select large number of pixel you select each pixel at once and then increment coordinates to select another

i.e

if you want to getcolor of large set of pixels ,You get a single pixel analyze its colour and then select another one . To avoid providing coordinates over and over again you can store coordinates of pixel you wanna select or writing a loop to select a particular area.

example :

If you want to get color of all 4 pixels , write a loop autoincrement value of coordinates from (0,0) to (1,1) , get colour of selected pixel ,Provide coordinates of next pixel and get colour (repeat till you want)

OR

declare an array which will hold coordinates of desired pixels `array => ([0]=> [0,0] [1]=> [0,1]....)`

Comment: Your results are not consistent with mine. Are you sure the mapping is from bottom-left? I get this: `0,0  = red; 0,1 = green; 1,0 = blue; 1,1 = transparent` which indicates top-left mapping.

Comment: Yes Your Statement is correct !  But Most Fundamentally i learned pixel and Computer graphics in C , python , java and PHP. When we used to analyze big picture like in face detection pixel are counted from bottom left by DEFAULT . Now it makes you mandatory to check wether its bottom-left or top-left ?